# dcast with if statement in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dcast

I am trying to reshape dataframe

```
cust_id<-sample(1:20,size = 100,replace = T)
prod_id<-sample(1:10,size=100,replace = T)
prod_id<-paste0("prodid",prod_id)
atm<-sample(1:10,size=100,replace = T)*100
atm[(sample(1:100,size=30,replace =F ))]<-0
sales<-data.frame(cust_id,prod_id,atm)  
sales
```

here is sales dataframe
if i want to change data.frame like this

> (if atm > 0 by cust_id, prod_id then value=1 and
>       atm < 0 by cust_id, prod_id then value=0)
>
> ```
>            cust_id prod_id1  prod_id2 prod_id3 prod_id4 ....
>               1      1          0        1       0
>               11     0          0        0       1
>               23     0          0        1       0
>               5      1          1        1       1
> ```

i tried to make it with dcast function.
but i can't use if statement in dcast.

please help...

Comment: dcast(sales, cust_id ~ prod_id, value.var = "atm", fun.aggregate = function(x) as.numeric(sum(x) > 0))

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz really thank you Juan! it was so easy to you and so difficult to me... i really appreciate it and thank you for your kindness! have a good day!